# OrientDB: AND operator inside eval() function

Tags: sql, eval, orientdb, and-operator

We have a very complex query and we are using eval() function to evaluate some data.

But it seems AND operator is not handled properly inside eval().

For example:

`if(eval('#20:34 IN out[@class='attempts'].in.@rid AND \'b\' IN out[@class='attempts'].choice'), true, false) as attempt_b`

In that example, we are expecting to get only the data with an @rid of `#20:34` AND with a "choice" property of 'b' that is to be return to true

"out" field there is the $current.@rid of our SELECT query.

This is the sample data:

```
out ------  in  ---- choices
14:3 ---- 20:34 ------ b
14:4 ---- 20:34 ------ a
14:7 ---- 20:34 ------ c
14:8 ---- 20:34 ------ d
```

Ex: `if(eval('#20:34 IN out[@class='attempts'].in.@rid AND \'" + choice + "\' IN out[@class='attempts'].choice'), true, false) as attempt_choice`

1.) `$current.@rid = #14:3 and choice is 'a'`

```
Return Output: true
Expected output: false (since there is no #20:34 with a choice of "A" in current.@rid which is #14:3)
```

2.) `$current.@rid = #14:3 and choice is 'b'`

```
Return Output: true
Expected output: true
```

3.) `$current.@rid = #14:3 and choice is 'c'`

```
Return Output: true
Expected output: false (since there is no #20:34 with a choice of "c" in current.@rid which is #14:3)
```

4.) `$current.@rid = #14:3 and choice is 'd'`

```
 Return Output: true
 Expected output: false (since there is no #20:34 with a choice of "d" in current.@rid which is #14:3)`
```

I don't know if it is just our query problem or in the orientdb. It would be a great help if someone can lead me to what we want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of quotes: you cared about escaping 'b' but not the rest. Try something like:

```
if(eval("#20:34 IN out[@class='attempts'].in.@rid AND 'b' IN out[@class='attempts'].choice"), true, false) as attempt_b
```